# Как серверу (Node.js/Express) передать заголовки с токеном?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Как добавить заголовки с токеном для отправки на сервер? Правильно ли я понимаю, нужно переопределить все ссылки страниц сайта (вместо a href="..." использовать new XMLHttpRequest() + header = token)?

Answer (score 0):

Если делается динамическое веб-приложение, то там возможно есть готовые вспомогательные функции для доступа к сервисам. Например AngularJS, React и т.д.

В противном случае придется не просто заменять аттрибут href. Придется использовать собственный javascript код для формирования сперва XMLHttpRequest (еще называют Ajax) и что главное, нужно понимать как обрабатывать ответ. Нужно ли перейти по указанному адресу (а тогда JWT будет утерян), либо просто динамически отобразить данные (что потребует еще кода на клиентской стороне). И чтобы этот код начать вызывать нужно на элементы типа  повещать обработчики событий, подробнее узнать об этом можно на [сайте Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F).